Automatic Scooter doesn't start on low fuel/idle
The scooter doesn't start when petrol becomes less than half and idle for more than a week.The self start struggles for minutes, finally kick start works after several kicks.But when petrol is full(>50%) it always starts even if idle for 2 weeks. What could be the reason? [Model Activa 4G]

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
